# How to imagine/draw this contour?

Tags: complex-analysis

I came across this contour in complex analysis today, given by $$\gamma(\theta)=1+2e^{i\theta}$$ where $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$

I want to imagine/know how this curve look like in physical reality? I know basic contours like circle of radius $r$, semicircles, arc, straight lines but I am not able to draw this curve on paper!

Attempt:

Let us denote by $w=2e^{i\theta}$ and $z=1+2e^{i\theta}$. So $$z-w=1$$
How do I draw it on paper? Are there any graphical software for quick visualization. I know basic GNUPLOT in case some one has any suggestions. But my primary aim is t draw it on paper.

Comment: $\theta \mapsto 2e^{i\theta}$ parametrizes a circle of radius two centered at the origin. If you add $1$ to every point on the circle, you just translate it along the real axis. You can also see this by noting that $$ |\gamma(\theta)-1|^2 = 4, $$ which is an equation of a circle of radius $2$ centered at $1+0i$.

Comment: @Sobi Thanks a lot. So it was not that hard. Nicely explained!!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\gamma(\theta) = 1 + 2(\cos\theta + i\sin \theta) = 2\cos \theta + 1 + i\sin \theta $

Denoting $x + iy = (x, y)$, we see that $(x(\theta) -1, y(\theta)) = (2\cos \theta, 2 \sin \theta)$ which holds iff $(x(\theta)-1)^2 + y(\theta)^2 = 4$, for $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi]$. This is the parametrization of a circle centered at $(1, 0)$ and radius $2$.